# Docker not opening ports on host for container on mac

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file to run two different versions of mysql:

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  mysql_5.6:
    image: mysql:5.6
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"

  mysql_latest:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
```

I start these with `docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up -d`. Running `docker ps` I get:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
9649cd3df592        mysql:latest        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Restarting (1) 28 seconds ago                       docker_mysql_latest_1
339b5a7f2262        mysql:5.6           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Restarting (1) 28 seconds ago                       docker_mysql_5.6_1
```

As you can see the Ports section is empty. Connecting with telnet or MySqlWorkbench gives me the expected connection refused. I'm on macOS Catalina and running Docker Desktop 2.3.0.3 (45519). I've added Docke to be allowed to open connections in the Firewall settings.

How can I make Docker open the ports on my mac?

Comment: You need to provide MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD or else use MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD if you don't want to use Admin password, but just for testing. Refer [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) for more details

Comment: What happens if you try to run one container directly without docker-compose ? Does the port mapping works this way ? (for example : `docker container run -d -p 3307:3306 mysql:5.6`

Comment: Looks like there is an issue while starting the container. Look at the status column, it says container is restarting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the issue was that I didn't specify the root password. This works now:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  mysql_5.6:
    image: mysql:5.6.44
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"

  mysql_latest:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
```